# How can I create a dynamic list of columns in SQL using Java, Spring Boot, and Hibernate?

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am getting the number of columns (heights) to be created from an input file. And from there i have to create height 1 .... height n columns in sql. Not sure about the best practices fro creating list of columns directly on SQL database.

i tried with List as column attribute type assumming that it would create directly. SQL is not accepting list

```
@Entity
@Table(name="precipitation")
public class Precipitation {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "metric")
    private Metric metric;

    @Column(name="timeData")
    private TimeData timeData;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "unit")
    private String unit;

    @Column(name = "isHeight")
    private String isHeight;

    @Column(name = "heights")
    private List<String> heights;

    @Column(name = "category")
    private String Category;`
```

Comment: That is not how you should design your table in SQL. SQL needs a fix design. What are you trying to do?

Comment: If you use PostgreSQL, you can use the advantage of JSON type.

Comment: @juergend i have three input csv files 1st file 3 height (columns), 2nd file has 5 heights (columns), 3rd file has 10 heights (columns). each height has different values i want to save all height accordingly for different files

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis is there a way to acheive something similar with sql